# Split big file in multiple files based on column

Tags: awk

I have a file with a semicolon as delimiter and headers. I would like to split that file based on the date column. The file has dates in ascending order.

The name of the output file should be as follows: **01**_XX_YYMMDD_YYMMDD.txt

**e.g.** 01_XX_210920_210920.txt

[image: Example]

Here's an example file:

```
--INPUT 
K;V1.00;;;;;;
P;01.01.2021 00:01;16;EXA;31;TESTA;95.9;XXXX
P;01.01.2021 00:02;33;EXA;31;TESTA;95.9;XYXY
P;02.01.2021 00:54;16;EXB;33;TESTB;94.0;DWAD
P;02.01.2021 00:56;11;EXB;33;TESTB;94.0;DADA
P;03.01.2021 01:00;16;EXC;32;TESTC;94.6;WEWEQ
P;03.01.2021 01:22;16;EXC;32;TESTC;94.6;QEQR
P;04.01.2021 02:39;16;EXD;33;TESTD;94.3;DFAG
```

The output should be as follows, while taking the previous file as example

```
--OUTPUT FILES
FILE1: 01_XX_210101_210101.txt
P;01.01.2021 00:01;16;EXA;31;TESTA;95.9;XXXX
P;01.01.2021 00:02;33;EXA;31;TESTA;95.9;XYXY

FILE2: 01_XX_210102_210102.txt
P;02.01.2021 00:54;16;EXB;33;TESTB;94.0;DWAD
P;02.01.2021 00:56;11;EXB;33;TESTB;94.0;DADA

FILE3: 01_XX_210103_210103.txt
P;03.01.2021 01:00;16;EXC;32;TESTC;94.6;WEWEQ
P;03.01.2021 01:22;16;EXC;32;TESTC;94.6;QEQR

FILE4: 01_XX_210104_210104.txt
P;04.01.2021 02:39;16;EXD;33;TESTD;94.3;DFAG
```

I tried AWK but no success because of the timestamp my file has…
Thank you!

x

**UPDATE: Solution**

```
    awk -F';' '
NR > 1 {
   dt = substr($2,9,2) substr($2,4,2) substr($2,1,2)
   print > ("01_LPR_" dt "_" dt ".txt")
}' input
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
awk -F';' '
NR > 1 {
   dt = substr($2,9,2) substr($2,4,2) substr($2,1,2)
   print > ("01_XX_" dt "_" dt ".txt")
}' input
```

---

For the updated requirements in comments below:

```sh
awk -F';' '
NR == 1 {
   hdr = $0
   next
}
{
   dt = substr($2,9,2) substr($2,4,2) substr($2,1,2)
}
dt != pdt {
   if (pdt) {
      print "END" > fn
      close(fn)
   }
   fn = "01_XX_" dt "_" dt ".txt"
   print hdr > fn
}
{
   print > fn
   pdt = dt
}
END {
   print "END" > fn
   close(fn)
}' input
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to also have K;V1.00;;;;;; at the beginning of each file and a simple String at the end like "END" of each file? The reason I am asking is because while dividing the file, we lose the headers

Comment: That can be done. I will updated answer in few moinutes

Comment: Thank you, I have modified my comment

Comment: I have updated my answer however please consider opening a new question for change of requirements as you can see that original and new commands are very different.

Answer (score 3):

With your shown samples, please try following `awk` code, this is using `close` function which will take care of avoiding too many opened files error too.

```
awk -F'\\.| |;' '
{
  outputFile="01_XX_"substr($4,3)$3 $2"_"substr($4,3)$3 $2".txt"
}
FNR>1{
  if(prev!=outputFile){
   close(prev)
  }
  print > (outputFile)
  prev=outputFile
}
'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the following script:

```
while read; do
  day=${REPLY:2:2}
  month=${REPLY:5:2}
  year=${REPLY:10:2}
  echo "$REPLY" >> 01_XX_${year}${month}${day}_${year}${month}${day}.txt
done<inputfile.txt
```

or the same in "oneline":

```
while read do echo "$REPLY" >> 01_XX_${REPLY:10:2}${REPLY:5:2}${REPLY:2:2}_${REPLY:10:2}${REPLY:5:2}${REPLY:2:2}.txt; done<inputfile.txt
```

Comment: Hello Saboteur, this generated files based on the month in my source file. It should be based on the days. Also the content of all file is REPLY instead of the actual content

Comment: Sorry, my mistake - updated my answer (replace REPLY with $REPLY and $myday with $day. Should work now